# Jquery .mouseover error, doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function main()
{
console.log("document ready, Javascript running");
  $(".openmenu_container").mouseover(function (){
console.log("mouseover triggered");
$(".sidebar").css("left","0px");
$(".openmenu_container").css("left","-200px");); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

  $(".sidebar").mouseleave(function (){
console.log("mouseleave triggered");
$(".sidebar").css("left","-200px");
$(".openmenu_container").css("left","40px");});
}}
$(document).ready(main);
```

I already have a functional sidebar on my website, using the .click() function. I want to make it so that mousing over the "open menu" button would be enough to open the menu, and that once the menu was opened, if the user moved their mouse out of the menu div, the menu would automatically close.

An error message is the only thing logged to the console, meaning that my code doesn't even run.  The error chrome gives me, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" doesn't make any sense, since the second ')' is needed to complete the .mouseover().  What am I doing wrong? Do I need a second argument for .mouseover?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsghfnrd/2/

Comment: Where is the closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not closed `)` and `}`.

In this line:

```
    $(".openmenu_container").css("left", "-200px"););
```

You missed `}` which must be closing the `mouseover event`.

Then below the sidebar event handler, you have an extra `}`.

So your corrected code would look like:

```
function main() {
    console.log("document ready, Javascript running");
    $(".openmenu_container").mouseover(function () {
        console.log("mouseover triggered");
        $(".sidebar").css("left", "0px");
        $(".openmenu_container").css("left", "-200px"); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )   
    });

    $(".sidebar").mouseleave(function () {
            console.log("mouseleave triggered");
            $(".sidebar").css("left", "-200px");
            $(".openmenu_container").css("left", "40px");
   });


}
    $(document).ready(main);
```

Also, hope you want to bind `mouseleave` event on `sidebar` outisde of `mouseover` event of `openmenu_container.`

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I did mean to have that outside of the mouseover event.  The sidebar div starts off-screen, so it doesn't really matter, but now that I think of it, I think it would be better to have it inside of the mouseover event.

Comment: Setup a jsfiddle, we would be able to solve it quickly.

Comment: I set up a jsfiddle.  It's my first time using jsfiddle and sharing it with other people, so I'm not sure if I set it up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function main() {
    console.log("document ready, Javascript running");
    $(".openmenu_container").mouseover(function () {
        console.log("mouseover triggered");
        $(".sidebar").css("left", "0px");
        $(".openmenu_container").css("left", "-200px");  
    });//add this

    $(".sidebar").mouseleave(function () {
            console.log("mouseleave triggered");
            $(".sidebar").css("left", "-200px");
            $(".openmenu_container").css("left", "40px");
   });


}
    $(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: The error's gone and the script runs, but .mouseover() still doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow will work. you can use an editor that highlight sytax for you!

```
function main()
{
console.log("document ready, Javascript running");
$(".openmenu_container").mouseover(function (){

  //console.log("mouseover triggered");
  $(".sidebar").css("left","0px");
  $(".openmenu_container").css(
          "left","-200px"
  ); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

  $(".sidebar").mouseleave(function (){
    //console.log("mouseleave triggered");
     $(".sidebar").css("left","-200px");
     $(".openmenu_container").css("left","40px");
 });
});
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

**Edit**
@mohamedrias's answer show better code analysis

Comment: Is it any different from what we've suggested below? Also you didn't explain where is the error

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("document ready, Javascript running");
    $(".openmenu_container").mouseover(function () {
        console.log("mouseover triggered");
        $(".sidebar").css("left", "0px");
        $(".openmenu_container").css("left", "-200px");  
    });//add this

    $(".sidebar").mouseleave(function () {
            console.log("mouseleave triggered");
            $(".sidebar").css("left", "-200px");
            $(".openmenu_container").css("left", "40px");
   });

});
```